VBA userform with interactive, editable pop-up to view and edit textbox
I have userform1 with a textbox1 and space on the form is limited. I am trying to create an interactive/editable 'pop-up' to give the user a larger space to enter/edit text in textbox1.
I created a mini userform2 with textbox2. I added a small commandbutton1 to userform1 that opens userform2, which works fine. I want textbox1 and textbox2 to mirror each other. As text is added/deleted/edited in one, the same occurs in the other.
I thought this would be easy, but I can't even get text from textbox1 to appear in textbox2. Here is what I've tried
Private Sub commandbutton1_Click() 'userform1 module
    Dim n As userform2
    Set n = New userform2
    n.Show 'works
    userform2.textbox2.Text = userform1.textbox1.Text 'not working
End Sub

Private Sub Userform_Initialize() 'userform2 module
    userform2.textbox2.Text = userform1.textbox1.Text 'not working
End Sub

Private Sub textbox2_Change() 'tried in userform1 and userform2 modules
    userform1.textbox1.Text = userform2.textbox2.Text 'not working
End Sub

Private Sub textbox1_Change() 'tried in userform1 and userform2 modules
    userform2.textbox2.Text = userform1.textbox1.Text 'not working
End Sub


EDITED
Userform1 contains textbox1 and commandbutton1
Userform2 contains textbox2
I was able to get textbox2 to match textbox1, but not the other way around. Also, I'm not able to keep userform2 in front. For example, if I 'touch' or 'click' on userform1, userform2 disappears behind userform1.
'code in userform1 module
Private Sub commandbutton1_Click()
    Dim N As userform2
    Set N = New userform2
    N.Show
 End Sub

Private Sub textbox1_Change() 'Works! If I type in textbox1
    userform2.textbox2.Text = Me.textbox1.Text
End Sub

'code in userform 2 module. Not able to keep userform2 in front of userform1 if I 'touch' or 'click' on userform1
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.textbox2.Text = userform1.textbox1.Text
    Me.StartUpPosition = 0
    Me.Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * Width)
    Me.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * Height)
End Sub

Private Sub textbox2_Change() 'If I type in textbox2, it does NOT appear in textbox1
    userform1.textbox1.Text = Me.textbox2.Text
End Sub


The following code applies to two userforms, each containing a textbox. The user can type text into either userform/textbox and it will be reflected in the other userform/textbox. You can take this example and adapt it to your needs.
ThisWorkbook module (optional - used just to get the show on the road):
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Call UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Userform1 module code:
Option Explicit

Private Sub commandbutton1_Click()
'    Dim N As UserForm2       >> Do not create a new instance
'    Set N = New UserForm2    >> of Userform2
    UserForm2.Show
 End Sub

Private Sub textbox1_Change()
    UserForm2.TextBox2.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Userform2 module code:
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  'Me.StartUpPosition = 0  >>Do NOT set this programmatically - set property at design time

  ' Position Userform2 to the right of Userform1
  UserForm2.Left = UserForm1.Left + UserForm1.Width
  UserForm2.Top = UserForm1.Top
End Sub

Private Sub textbox2_Change()
  UserForm1.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox2.Text
End Sub


Userform1 and Userform2 need the following property set:
ShowModal: False
StartUpPosition: 0 - Manual (optional for Userform1)
Textboxes in both userforms need the following properties set:
EnterKeyBehaviour: True
Multiline: True

Thank you for your response. I have a command button on the worksheet to open Userform1, so I skipped your first block of code: Private Sub Workbook_Open.  With that said, I'm not able to get this to work.

You don't really say what isn't working. It works fine for me using your scenario. The only thing I can think of is that Userform2 opens directly on top of Userform1 and you just need to drag Userform2 off to the side a bit to expose Userform1 underneath.

please see the edits above. I hope I've done a better job of explaining. Thank you so much for your willingness to help me.

Glad to help. There were two main issues with your code:

You should not have created a new instance of Userform2. That changed all your references to the Userform2 object which was never opened. The reference to the object that was opened was actually 'N'.
StartupPosition property needs to be set at design time.

I have updated my answer accordingly. This should now get you moving forward.
